# Update JAX array based on values in another array

Tags: jax

I have a Jax array X like this:

```
[[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]]
```

How do I set the values of this array to 1, whose indices are given by array Y:

```
[[[1 2]
 [1 2]]

 [[0 2]
 [0 1]]

 [[1 0]
 [1 0]]]
```

Desired output:

```
([[[0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 0.]],

       [[1., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0.]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to approach this. First let's define the arrays:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

x = jnp.zeros((3, 2, 3))
indices = jnp.array([[[1, 2],
                      [1, 2]],
                     [[0, 2],
                      [0, 1]],
                     [[1, 0],
                      [1, 0]]])
```

One way to do this is to use typical numpy-style broadcasting of indices. It might look like this:

```py
i = jnp.arange(3).reshape(3, 1, 1)
j = jnp.arange(2).reshape(2, 1)
x = x.at[i, j, indices].set(1)
print(x)
```

```
[[[0. 1. 1.]
  [0. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 0. 1.]
  [1. 1. 0.]]

 [[1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 0.]]]
```

Another option is to use a double-`vmap` transformation to compute the batched indices:

```py
f = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(lambda x, i: x.at[i].set(1)))
print(f(x, indices))
```

```
[[[0. 1. 1.]
  [0. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 0. 1.]
  [1. 1. 0.]]

 [[1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 0.]]]
```